# Layout won't update on keyboardWillHide method

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, keyboard, autolayout

I have been able to update the layout constraints for my scrollView using the keyboardWillShow method. However when trying to do the same in the keyboardWillHide method, the layout won't update (resulting in a scrollView that is cut off where the keyboard used to start). Any hints as to how to fix this? Thanks!!

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    keyboardHeightSubtraction = keyboardFrame.size.height
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -keyboardHeightSubtraction).isActive = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}


@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you currently create conflicts in constraints so  make it once in `viewDidLoad` and manage it's constant in the 2 functions like this\

```
var botCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

//

```
botCon = scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
botcon.isActive = true
```

//

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    botCon.constant = -1 * keyboardHeightSubtraction 
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}


@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    botCon.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot. It's still not apparent to me how I caused a conflict in constraints. Mind explaining more about this?

Comment: every anchor constraint you create is being added to the old constraints as the keyboard is shown and hidden a lot , this will create constraints that conflict with the old ones which makes auto-layout breaks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIEdgeInsects` and capture the height of the Keyboard and add a custom padding depending upon your view to space the scroll view from the bottom and on keyBoard dismiss set back the scrollView Insect back to zero.

`var contentPadding: CGFloat = 60`

---

**KeyBoard Will Appear**

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

    var contentInset: UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
    contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height + contentPadding // custom padding
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
}
```

---

**Keyboard Will Disappear**

```
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInset: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
}
```

Comment: Great solution too. Much appreciated!